# Using struct.pack

Tags: python, struct, int, unsigned

My code looks like this :

```
import struct

str = "AAAAAAA"
len = len(str)+32

package = struct.pack("!H",len)
print repr(package)
```

the result is :

```
"\x00'"
```

When I use `len = len(str)`
the result is  `\x00\x07`

Why when `len` is larger than 32,it is not working?

Comment: First, don't shadow builtin names like: `str` and `len`. Give them different names (prepend them with an _ for example).

Comment: Why do you think that output is wrong? Its doing exactly what `repr()` is supposed to do here, creating a printable representation of the packed structure's contents. What output would you expect to see here?

Comment: Notice the __'__ in `"\x00'"` (after the last _0_). That's the _apostrophe_ char: _ASCII_ code 0x27 = 39 = 7(`len("AAAAAAA")`) + 32.

Comment: use the unpack function to obtain back the value: `struct.unpack('>H',package)`. It will output 39

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the `"\x00'"` result. It's a mixture of a string hexadecimal character code value and a regular printable ASCII character. If it were displayed  purely in hexadecimal character codes, it would be `"\x00x\x27"`.

The `\x27` in decimal is the integer `39`, which is the result of `len(str)+32`. It's also the character code of the `'` (single quote) character, which is part of what `repr()` is displaying.